# Edit text file on server using VB

Tags: vb.net, file, webserver

I would like to edit a text file on a server I have and I'm not really sure to begin. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
dim username as string
dim password as string
dim serveraddr as string
username = "MyUsername"
password = "MyPassword"
serveraddr = "MyServer.hosting.com"
ConnectToServer(serveraddr, username, password)
WriteToFile("sample.txt", "Hello World")
```

Something like this. Obviously I just made the last two "methods" up so I guess those are what I am looking for except I don't know what they are called.

Comment: What kind of server? HTTP, FTP, UNC file share?

Comment: @GSerg  Its an http web hosting server (5gbfree.com)

Comment: You can't edit the file on the server.  You must download it, edit it locally, and then upload the new file.  You can find plenty of information on those three tasks separately.

Comment: what server type (ftp , sql ..etc) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Best Way Would Be To Delete The File From The Server And Rewriting It From Your App , Else If You Want To Add Info To The File You Can Download It To The Local Machine Then Add The Info , Delete It From The Server And Re-uploading  it

Function For Deleting it

```
Private Function deletefile(ByRef filepathinftp As String, ByRef password As String, ByRef username As String)
    Dim ftp As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(filepathinftp), FtpWebRequest)

    Try
        ftp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile
        Dim ftpResponse As FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
        ftpResponse = ftp.GetResponse()
        ftpResponse.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Function
```

Function For Downloading From An Ftp

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("File Path In Ftp Example: ftp ://mysite.com/file.txt"), FtpWebRequest)
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

                ' This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
                request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")

                Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

                Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
                Dim text As String = reader.ReadToEnd
```

Finally here is the function for uploading

```
Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String, ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
    Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)

    ' Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
    Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

    ' Provide the WebPermission Credintials
    _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)

    ' By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
    ' after a command is executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False

    ' set timeout for 20 seconds
    _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000

    ' Specify the command to be executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    ' Specify the data transfer type.
    _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True

    ' Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
    _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length

    ' The buffer size is set to 2kb
    Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
    Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte

    ' Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
    Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()

    Try
        ' Stream to which the file to be upload is written
        Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

        ' Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
        Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)

        ' Till Stream content ends
        Do While contentLen <> 0
            ' Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
            _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
            contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
        Loop

        ' Close the file stream and the Request Stream
        _Stream.Close()
        _Stream.Dispose()
        _FileStream.Close()
        _FileStream.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the download method and I keep getting an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Comment: Well I fixed the error with downloading the file but could you explain the arguments for the uploading file function?

Comment: if you wana upload test.txt you got to put the path ftp://whatever.com/whatever/test.txt